# Change the default value of a class property in an object

Tags: php, oop

is there a way to change the value of a class property in current object and set it as default value for all the objects that are going to be created after it in php?

Comment: An example of what you want to do would help.

Comment: You can create a class with two fields, one of them make static. The static field will store the default value for the dynamic field.  At the same time in the constructor, you initialize dynamic property with the value from static property. After that, when you need to change the default value of property in a newly created object, you can just change the value of the static field.

Comment: @Lyudmila, post as answer with code example.